# Reasons not to use a CSS reset?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I heard that many developers are not recommending using CSS reset, what are the reason for it?

for example:
[What are the rules for portable CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927543/what-are-the-rules-for-portable-css/7927653#7927653)

Comment: Where have you heard that? Can you post links so we can get some context?

Comment: @pleasedontbelong - Not a duplicate. He is asking for reasons **not** to use a CSS reset.

Comment: [here](http://sixrevisions.com/css/should-you-reset-your-css/), [here](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20080419/reset-style-sheets-are-bad/), [here](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/no_css_reset)

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/no_css_reset

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate of that question. Reopen.

Comment: To me it's a duplicate. If not we'll end up with questions like `is it NOT OK to use css reset?`, `Problems using css reset`, `problems not using css reset`, `what are the problems using css reset?`.. and the answer is likely to be found on the same question. (Demonstration: 2 of the 3 links in @Ross Comment can be found on the page I marked as duplicated; and almost in every answer i could find a reason why not to use css reset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a CSS reset, lots of HTML elements become unusable : titles are small border-less and margin-less, input elements are misformed, etc... You need to restyle all these elements, which is more work.

Some people think that this process of destyling/restyling is unnecessary, error-prone, and that it removes some necessary differences between platforms. Most notably, input elements are typically styled by a browser according to its host platform (windows, mac, etc...) and some people think that UI consistency should be respected even inside a browser.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Reset is found there to normalize the CSS across browsers and gives you easier and more intuitive design possibilities.

For instance, when you use `<h1>` without a CSS reset/normalization, it will have larger `font-size`, some `margin`s, and a bold `font-weight`, with a CSS reset, it would look like a normal text, and it allows you to shape it the way you want, without worrying about the browser defaults which may vary between browsers.

The question you should ask yourself, **do you want it**?

Remember that a CSS reset does not have to be absolute, if you want to remove all margins and paddings, but retain font size and weight, you could use the classic `* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }` rather then using a full-powered CSS reset.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a website,
and you know html & CSS like the back if your hand,
and you can test directly on all major operating systems without compromise,
You're proficient in correcting errors/conflicts with old browsers,
or you are making a website for one browser only.

You may not need a CSS reset or it would be best for you to make your own.

But if you're making a typical modern website and you want to avoid 
cross browser conflicts, a reset sheet should "set" the html elements to a similar 
playing field.

Many reset sheets interfere with styling too much, all you really want is a default like  [CSSesta](http://cssesta.tk) or [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)